# Complete Python Noob

Tags: python

I need to convert a file from one format to another. The input file will be formatted as follows:

> >Word
>
> Description

and I need to change it to this format:

> Word Description

Does anyone know what I can do to format it this way? Thanks in advance for your help.Also it is worth noting that I don't know what the file will be. Each line will be the same length but there will be a random number of pairings.
Basically I don't know how many lines there will be or what the lines will be
Thank you so so so much for your help!!!!

So far all I have is:

```
with open("insertfilenamehere.txt") as file:
  lines=file.readlines()
```

I am unsure of how to re-format everything

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and a description of what's not working about it.  You are going to need to do three things: 1) read the content of the file into a string, 2) manipulate the string to fit the requirements, and 3) write it back out to a file.  Google these things, and you should be able to figure it out.  Good Luck!

Comment: So first I opened the file, did lines=file.readlines() and I'm not sure where to go from here to re-format it

Comment: You can edit your own post to provide more information. Edit the post and provide some code that you've written to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're reading the text properly, you can write it back out in a similar way:

```
with open("new_file.txt", "w+") as out_file:
  for line in fixed_text:
    out_file.write(line)
```

But first, you'l have to fix the text.  I don't want to give it all away, but it'll look something like this:

```
fixed_text = []
for line in lines: # iterate over lines of text you have
  fixed_line = fix_line(line) # "line" will refer to one element of "lines" at a time until done
  fixed_text.append(fixed_line) # add fixed line to new list for later
```

This is a rough outline, Google lots and post any problems you run into in a new question.  Good luck dude!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are "ConfusedStudent", I am not going to give you the code directly, but you are halfway there. You have the lines stored in lines. this is iterable....ie you can loop over these lines. Now you just need to figure out how to loop over them. One hint is that you don't have to increment by one as you loop. Look at the documentation for `range()`which can be used with a for loop. Alternatively you can use a while loop. If the usual while loop is something along the lines of

```
x=0
while x<10
    x+=1
    #do something....like *concatenate*(hint: google this) strings together
```

then how might you increment by more than 1? finally in order to put all of the lines back into another file you will to open() again, but this time with the 'w' optional  parameter which allows you to write to a file. Use close() to close the file. You will probably need to look at the documentation and some examples. Section 7.2 on this link is a good place to start: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html